# Integration with Beta Function $\beta$

Tags: integration, contour-integration, line-integrals, cauchy-principal-value, beta-function

Given that:

$$\int_{c\ -\ j\infty}^{c\ +\ j\infty}\left({\sigma\,x^{-1}}\right)^u\beta\left(u,a\right)du=\left(1-{x \over \sigma}\right)^{a-1}$$

whereby $\sigma>0$, $a>0$ and  $x$ is a real number which could be both positive or negative

I need help proving this statement using Cauchy's residue theorem

Comment: It would be more helpful for people to answer, if you define all the variables and constant used in the question.

Comment: @Mann sure! $\sigma>0$, $a>0$ and $x$ is a real number which could be both positive or negative

Comment: $\beta(u,a)$ is a Mellin transform of $(1-x)^{a-1}$ for $x\in (0,1)$ and zero for $x\ge1$.

$$\beta(u,a)=\int_0^1  x^{u-1}(1-x)^{a-1} dx$$

Mellin inversion:

$$ \int_{c-j\infty}^{c+j\infty} \left({x \over \sigma} \right)^{-u} \beta(u,a)du = \left(1-{x\over \sigma}\right)^{a-1}$$

Comment: @shilov thanks. u could make it as the answer if you want to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\beta(u,a)$ is a Mellin transform of $(1−x)^{a−1}$ for $x∈(0,1)$ and zero for $x≥1$.
$$β(u,a)=\int_{0}^{1}x^{u−1}(1−x)^{a−1}dx$$
Mellin inversion:
$$\int_{c\ -\ j\infty}^{c\ +\ j\infty}\left(x \over \sigma\right)^{−u}β\left(u,a\right)du=\left(1−{x\over \sigma}\right)^{a−1}$$